# What will happen if I insert a string into DynamoDB but its length exceeds the limitation 400 KB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I don't think DynamoDB will cut the string to 400KB, since that's unsafe. So will DynamoDB throw an error when I try to insert a string longer than the limitation?

Comment: did you try? (BTW yes it will return 400 bat request.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you use, you'll get an exception. Basically it will be a wrapper around 400th HTTP code, returned by low-level DynamoDB REST API:

Something like:

```
ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}
```

Or:

```
Item size to update has exceeded the maximum allowed size (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

Or:

```
Could not write to DynamoDB: ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size for key :largeAttribute status code: 400, request id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```